# How can I extend the length of the batterystats history?

Tags: battery, battery-life, usb-debugging

I am doing some power consumption analysis using Batterystats and Battery Historian. The problem that I am facing is that the length of history I can get from the phones varies widely form brand to brand.

On Samsung phones, for example, I have gotten history of up to 5 days, whereas with Pixel phones I can't get more than 1hr of history. **Is there a way to increase the time period logged by the system?**

Currently, when I do a power consumption test, I follow these steps:

1. Reset logs with `adb shell dumpsys batterystats --reset`
2. Run `adb shell dumpsys batterystats --enable no-auto-reset` to prevent resetting of the logs
3. After the test, retrieve the logs with `adb bugreport bugreport.zip`
4. Analyze the logs in Battery Historian.

But I can't find any ways to get a consistent history from phone to phone. As stated above, the history length will be different depending on the brand, even if the test period is the same.

I would like to get at least 12 hours worth of data to perform overnight tests. Even better if I can get multi-day data for long term testing.

Edit: Edited the steps I take to test to add more detail and clarity.

Comment: In settings app on my Pixel4a I get 24 hours history. You should edit your question and post the full commands you are using, not only some parameters of an unknown command.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Robert, I have edited to add more detail. What settings are you referring to in your Pixel?

Comment: If I open Settings app -> Battery -> Battery usage I get power usage of the last 24 hours as graph and the involved [system] apps.

Comment: By keeping `no-auto-reset` enabled I've been able to get battery stats for months. Currently one of my device is at 131 days. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Gnk.png). But `no-auto-reset` doesn't persist across device reboots. So it must be set before unplugging charger which may clear battery stats if some [other conditions](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-12.0.0_r1/core/java/com/android/internal/os/BatteryStatsImpl.java#13523) also meet.

Comment: @Robert, unfortunately the Battery Usage stats on the phone don't have the detailed information I need from the batterystats logs and it's the logs that I can't get long term data from.